# Add a linear layout to the view after a ExpandableListView without being covered by the ExpandableListView when populated?

Tags: android

What happens is when I populate my list view the linear layout below the ExpandableListView will disappear. I want  the "@+id/bottomActionBarAppointments" layout to be visible always on the screen. I do not want to set a static height to the ExpandableListView.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Following is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AppointmentsActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListViewAppointments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" >
    </ExpandableListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomActionBarAppointments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after trying few changes.
I used layout_weight property to allow each linear layout to share a specific portion of the screen.
Following is my layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AppointmentsActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="0.8">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListViewAppointments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomActionBarAppointments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/green" 
        android:layout_weight="0.1">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```